# MLton on Alpine Linux

Tags: alpine-linux, mlton

I am encountering problems to install and run the [MLton compiler](http://mlton.org) in a [Docker](https://www.docker.com) container using [Alpine Linux](https://www.alpinelinux.org).
Is there a way to install this compiler on this system?

## Try #1

Using the standard `alpine base image and the binary distribution of MLton:

```
$ curl http://sourceforge.net/projects/mlton/files/mlton/20130715/mlton-20130715-1.amd64-linux.tgz --output mlton-20130715-1.amd64-linux.tgz
$ docker build .
```

With the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
COPY mlton-20130715-1.amd64-linux.tgz /
RUN apk add --no-cache bash build-base gmp-dev linux-headers \
 && tar xf /mlton-20130715-1.amd64-linux.tgz \
        --directory /usr/ \
        --strip-components 1 \
 && echo 'print "Hello, world!\n";' >> hello-world.sml \
 && mlton hello-world.sml
```

Docker build fails with the following error message, probably because `glibc` is missing.

> /usr/bin/mlton: line 52: /usr/lib/mlton/mlton-compile: No such file or directory

## Try #2

The same as above, with a base Docker image that embeds `glibc`:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
```

This time, `mlton` runs, but produces the following error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/lib/mlton/targets/self/libmlton.a(platform.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> ...
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> call to system failed with exit status 1:
>
> gcc -o hello-world /tmp/fileGEluFu.o /tmp/fileYnNjh9.o -L/usr/lib/mlton/targets/self -lmlton -lgdtoa -lm -lgmp -m64 -Wl,-znoexecstack

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Of course, the `curl` command does not work due to SourceForge's redirect, but this is not the problem.

Comment: I tried the latest version, `20180207`. As with yours, `mlton` runs but complains about `undefined reference to __snprintf_chk`. Seems related to https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/27